# Problem with divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Proof of the following without induction :

$13| 3^{n+2}   +   4^{2n+1}$

for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

Any help is apprciated.

Comment: Do you mean $(4^2)n + 1$, $(4^2)(n+1)$, $(4^{2n}) + 1$, or $4^{2n + 1}$ or something else completely?

Comment: $3^{n+2}$ or $3^n + 2$, $4^{2n} + 1$ or $4^2n+1$? Any attempts?

Answer (score 1):

First, rewrite as:

$$\begin{align}3^{n+2} + 4^{2n+1} &= 9\cdot3^n + 4\cdot4^{2n}\\
&= 9\cdot3^n + 4\cdot16^{n}\end{align}$$

Then, use modular arithmetic to prove divisibility by $13$:

$$\begin{align}9\cdot3^n + 4\cdot16^{n}&= 9\cdot3^n + 4\cdot(13+3)^n\\
&\equiv 9\cdot3^n + 4\cdot3^n\pmod{13}\\
&= 3^n\cdot(9 + 4)\pmod{13}\\
&= 3^n\cdot13\pmod{13}\\
&\equiv 0 \pmod{13}\end{align}$$

Hence, $3^{n+2} + 4^{2n+1} \equiv 0 \pmod{13}$, i.e. $13 | (3^{n+2} + 4^{2n+1})$ for all non-negative integers $n$.

Comment: yes that is what i need to prove ... but i don´t understand how and  why you go from line 1 to line 2

Comment: I've made it more explicit, do have a look.

Comment: I am sorry but i still don´t understand what you do in the first line after "Then, use modular arithmetic to prove divisibility by 13". Which property for modular arithmetic (or theorem) do you use there ??

Comment: The property that $(a +b)^n \equiv b^n \pmod a$